# replace ObjectId field with custom string for ObjectIdColumn in TypeORM/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I have a NestJs REST API and use TypeORM with MongoDB. I want to create a entity called `project`. I started with a basic entity and I just read that I should use `ObjectIdColumn` instead of `PrimaryColumn` for MongoDB.

```
@Entity()
export class Project extends BaseEntity {
  // The technical project name
  @ObjectIdColumn({ generated: false })
  public id: ObjectID;

  // The display name
  @Column({ unique: true })
  public name: string;

  // The project successor
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public successorId: ObjectID;

  // Configuration stuff for that project
  @Column()
  public configuration: object;
}
```

I would like to know if it's possible to replace that object id column with a primary column of type string. The `id` field is based on a special pattern, e.g. the name field

> my awesome project

would result into

> my-awesome-project

for the id field. Sure I made use of `generated: false` but I have to pass in a custom string instead of an `ObjectID`. Currently this is not possible because the docs say the `ObjectID`

> Can be a 24 byte hex string, 12 byte binary string or a Number. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/ObjectID.html

So what needs to get done to use a custom string as an ID field? The only thing I can think of is creating a second field e.g. `theRealId` and treat it like the ID field and ignore the autogenerated ObjectId...

Comment: As I read the documentation is exactly like you're assuming... Add an extra field for your own id and ignore Mongo's standard _id. (I would anyway not name your field "real id", but rather like "my id")

Answer (score 2):

From what I've learnt, here is what you can do

```
@Entity()
export class UserEntity
{
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  _id: string;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  // The display name
  @Column({ unique: true })
  public name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public successorId: ObjectID;

  @Column()
  public configuration: object;
}
```

- MongoDB will use `_id` as an internal id, that you do not expose through your program (and api, then)
- You will work with the `id`, "normally', and it will be your primary key, generating automatically and so on

Source : personal learning, and [Udemy course : NestJS Zero to Hero - Modern TypeScript Back-end Development](https://www.udemy.com/course/nestjs-zero-to-hero)